# Bug: The Woot badge

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

I just received the Woot badge on SO, neat. But the strange thing is, I only visited the site once when I first noticed the badge. The requirement is to visit the site every day for 30 days, so how come I got the badge?

edit: wait, I think I get it. I have to visit SO, not Woot. Right?

Comment: * facepalm     *

Comment: Awesome!       `

Comment: Note that woot is the old name of the enthousiast badge

Answer (score 20):

Wouldn't you be a little worried if StackOverflow could track how often you visited woot.com?

Comment: It's not too crazy to think. There are many partnered sites that share where you've been and what you've looked at with each other. It's part of the reason "cookies" come up when discussing "privacy" so often.

Answer (score 10):

Yes you have to visit SO, woot is just sponsoring the badge for now. It will switch back to enthusiast (its real name, and reason it seems out of alphabetical order in the badges listing) after the sponsor period elapses.

Answer (score 4):

I have to admit, after I first saw the Woot badge, I started going to woot.com for a few days as a little experiment to see if that was actually what you had to do to get it. I eventually figured it out and stopped going.

And yes... facepalm.

Comment: But Woot was happy.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the badge is for visiting StackOverflow every day for 30 days.

Answer (score 2):

You do realize that if you hover your mouse over the badge, it will give you a pop-up description of the badge, ... right?

**Edit:**

I guess the tooltip wasn't that clear about what it meant.

> Visited the site each day for 30 days

Which makes one wonder, what other [Badge descriptions [are] ambiguous](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3032/badge-descriptions-ambiguous)?

Comment: Have you read the description? It says 'the site' not 'stackoverflow'.

Comment: Point taken, I heard about it in the pod-cast, so I never really checked it out.