# Don't understand the criterion for the Enlightened badge

Tags: support, badges, enlightened-badge

As you can see in my [SO user page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46642/martinho-fernandes) I have two Enlightened badges. But I have three answers accepted with at least 10 up votes.

Why is that? Is Enlightened meant as "with *more* than 10" instead of *at least*?

And what's the meaning of "First answer ..." in the badge description?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it is at least 10 vote, not more than. And by first, it means you were the first person to answer the question. So you should get it if you were the first answer, it has net 10 upvotes and is the accepted answer. Something I don't know is if/how it takes into account deleted answers, or for that matter edits. I would guess its simply if you were the first in, period, not factoring in those pieces, but I don't know.

Comment: I am sure edits do not count, because I had just gained the second one when I posted this question, and I had made edits.

Comment: Also, if you are second time answer, but the first delete his own - and you got >=10 - you will earn the badge. Just experienced that .. :)

Answer (score 3):

"First answer" means that you were the first person to answer the question. If you look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410719/notimplementedexception-are-they-kidding-me/410800#410800), you will see that you were not the first person to answer, and therefore it's not elegible for the Enlightened badge.

Comment: interesting, i just assumed it meant you could only get the badge once

Comment: That was my assumption also.

Comment: I have a problem understanding several badge descriptions at first glance... especially the ones using the ambiguous word "first" in the description.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3032

Comment: I got the Enlightened badge for the very first answer I ever posted on SO, so I that's what I thought "first" meant. Imagine my surprise when I got another one... :-\ Thanks for clarifying.