# Mark which badges are capable of being won > 1 time

Tags: feature-request, badges, information-display

When I see the badges list, I'm unsure which ones are being capable of being won more than once.  Could we highlight these badges in some way?

**EDIT:**  I reviewed the entire list today, and if you click on each badge, you'll see the text "This badge can be awarded multiple times." (as Jeff points out) for those badges that can be won more than once.  The key is though that you have to click through to see it.  I've edited TheTXI's answer to show what is now current.

This feature request is for the [badges page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges) to show which ones can be won multiple times, so you don't have to go to every badge page to figure it out.

Comment: "First answer was accepted with at least 10 up votes" "can be received multiple times". Obvious isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but I think there are some that allow multiple wins but don't say.

Comment: It's only obvious if "first answer" is unambiguous.

Comment: @Lance Roberts: which?

Comment: @Tomas, the confusion came because there used to be badges that were awarded multiple times, that now aren't.  See my edit.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I actually answered a question like this a while back and here is my answer (provided more detailed descriptions to all the regular badges):

[Badge descriptions ambiguous](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3032/badge-descriptions-ambiguous/3033#3033)

- **Altruist** - First bounty you manually awarded on another person's question (once)
- **Announcer** - Shared a link to a question that was visited by 25 unique IP addresses in 3 days (once)
- **Autobiographer** - Fill out your user profile (once)
- **Benefactor** - First bounty you manually awarded on your own question (once)
- **Booster** - Shared a link to a question that was visited by 300 unique IP addresses in 4 days (once)
- **Beta** - Be a member of the site's beta period (once)
- **Citizen Patrol** - Flag your first post (once)
- **Civic Duty** - Cast any combination of 300 up and down votes (once)
- **Cleanup** - First rollback of a question or answer (once)
- **Commentator** - Left 10 comments on questions and answers (once)
- **Copy Editor** - Edited 500 posts (once)
- **Critic** - Awarded first time you cast a down vote (once)
- **Deputy** - Achieved a flag weight of 500 by reviewing and flagging appropriately (once)
- **Disciplined** - Deleted your own post that had a score of at least +3 (once)
- **Editor** - First edit to a question or answer (once)
- **Electorate** - Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions (once)
- **Enlightened** - You are the first to answer a question. Your answer is accepted. Your answer scores at least +10. (multiple)
- **Enthusiast(Woot!)** - Visited the site for 30 days straight (once)
- **Famous Question** - Asked a question with 10,000 views (multiple)
- **Fanatic** - Visit the site for 100 straight days (once)
- **Favorite Question** - Your question is favorited by 25 people (multiple)
- **Generalist** - Active in many different tags (once)
- **Good Answer** - Answer voted up 25 times (multiple)
- **Good Question** - Question voted up 25 times (multiple)
- **Great Answer** - Answer voted up 100 times (multiple)
- **Great Question** - Question voted up 100 times (multiple)
- **Guru** - Accepted Answer and Score of at least +40 (multiple)
- **Investor** - First bounty you offered on another person's question (once)
- **Legendary** - Earned 200 daily reputation 150 times (once)
- **Mortarboard** - Earned at least 200 reputation in a single day (once)
- **Necromancer** - Answer a question more than 60 days after it's posting and score at least +5 (multiple)
- **Nice Answer** - Answer voted up 10 times (multiple)
- **Nice Question** - Question voted up 10 times (multiple)
- **Notable Question** - Question viewed 2,500 times (multiple)
- **Organizer** - Awarded upon the first time you retag a question (once)
- **Outspoken** - Posted 10 messages in chat that were starred by 10 different users (once)
- **Peer Pressure** - Deleted your own post after it scored at least -3 (once)
- **Popular Question** - Question viewed 1,000 times (multiple)
- **Populist** - Your answer has 2x the score as the accepted answer. Accepted answer must be at least +10 (multiple)
- **Precognitive** - Followed the Area 51 proposal for this site before it entered the commitment phase (once)
- **Promoter** - First bounty you offered on your own question (once)
- **Proofreader** - Approved or rejected 100 suggested edits (once)
- **Publicist** - Shared a link to a question that was visited by 1000 unique IP addresses in 5 days (once)
- **Pundit** - Left 10 comments with score of 5 or more (once)
- **Reversal** - Provided answer of +20 score to a question of -5 score (multiple)
- **Revival** - Answered more than 30 days later as first answer scoring 2 or more (multiple)
- **Scholar** - Awarded the first time you accept an answer on a question you post (once)
- **Self-Learner** - Accepted your own answer and scored at least +3 (once)
- **Sportsmanship** - Upvoted 100 competing answers (once)
- **Stellar Question** - Question favorited by 100 users (multiple)
- **Strunk & White** - Awarded after you edit 80 questions or answers (once)
- **Student** - Awarded after asking a question with a single up vote (once)
- **Suffrage** - Used 30 votes in a day (once)
- **Supporter** - Awarded after casting your first up vote (once)
- **Synonymizer** - First approved tag synonym (once)
- **Tag Editor** - First Tag Wiki Edit (once)
- **Talkative** - Posted 10 messages, with 1 or more starred, in chat (once)
- **Taxonomist** - Created a tag that is used on 50 questions (once)
- **Teacher** - Awarded after receiving your first up vote on an answer (once)
- **Tenacious** - Zero score accepted answers: more than 5 and 20% of total (once)
- **Tumbleweed** - Ask a question that gets no comments, no answers, and low views over the course of a week (once)
- **Unsung Hero** - Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total (once)
- **Vox Populi** - Used the maximum 40 votes in a day (once)
- **Yearling** - be a member of the site for a year (multiple)

Comment: Enthusiast _is_ only awarded once. Otherwise, everyone who has the Fanatic badge would have, by definition, at lest three Enthusiasts.

Comment: That doesn't prove that Enthusiast isn't provided twice for two separate 30 day periods.

Comment: Yearling is awarded more than once

Comment: According to this, Peer Pressure is one-time-only (for understandable reason): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33792/does-the-peer-pressure-badge-get-awarded-more-than-once

Comment: @TheTXI, this is a bit outdated.

Comment: Won't it be trivial to add this to the badge list page, which is what the OP asked for in the first place? It'd be better to use a icon instead of text.

Comment: @Geoffrey, I've been on the fence about making a community-edited badges page, and you've pushed me over the edge. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions

Comment: This list is wrong (e.g. the Tumbleweed), according to information using the Jeff Atwoods answer.

Comment: @Tomas, I just edited the list and updated the one/multiple phrases.

Answer (score 10):

I would like to introduce a possible solution: Update the badge-icons in such a way: 
[image]
to indicate the possibility to earn it more than once.

Answer (score 4):

I completely agree that this issue **should be solved somehow for now and for ever**.

Just simply **display the information somehow in the badge list!** Easy and working, right?
It could be done elegantly and synoptically e.g. by simple symbols like 1, +1 or the like.

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule, badges talk about "first" (ie, first flagged, first upvote), are only awarded once. However, I completely understand that their is confusion about this, especially due to "enlightened" which has first in it but can be awarded multiple times. I think even just adding parenthetically to the description "awarded only once" would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Badges that can be awarded more than once will say so in the description on the badge page, for example:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/33/favorite-question

> {blah blah blah badge description}. **This badge can be awarded multiple times.**

Comment: -1: The OP asked for the badge list!