# Do I get Enthusiast badges for the same 100-day period for one Fanatic badge?

Tags: discussion, activity-badges

It seems appropriate that awarding one Fanatic badge should erase 3 Enthusiast badges earned in the same period. If it's already so, please close.

Comment: It should NOT in this case, though: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11652/how-addicted-to-stack-overflow-are-you/59336#59336

Comment: How is it possible to earn multiple Enthusiast badges on a single site with one account in the first place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is never the case with any of the badges. Enthusiast can only be earned once, so you don't get three on the way to Fanatic, but it makes sense to leave the one you had. For a much simpler example, if you post a question that gets 100 score, you'll get [Nice question](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/20/nice-question), [Good question](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/21/good-question), and [Great question](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/22/great-question); the previous one isn't revoked as you get the next one, it just means you've earned both.

There's a general rule that you never lose a badge once you've gotten it, even if you no longer meet the criteria for it, so losing badges you *do* meet the criteria for would be massively confusing

Comment: Thanks! There are many badges that you can earn more than once, so maybe the badge list should somehow indicates that.

Comment: @Geo The individual badge pages do ( [This badge can be awarded multiple times](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/22/great-question) ), but you could post a feature request to show it on the badge list if you think it'd be useful

Comment: Thanks again. There's already a [question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7424/mark-which-badges-are-capable-of-being-won-1-time) and [King Atwood](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7424/mark-which-badges-are-capable-of-being-won-1-time/39189#39189) didn't get it.

Comment: @Geoffrey, I went ahead and made a community badge page that will have more info than the /badges page: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions