# How can we see if a badge can be awarded multiple times?

Tags: feature-request, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mark which badges are capable of being won > 1 time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7424/mark-which-badges-are-capable-of-being-won-1-time)
>   [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

In the [Badges page](https://stackoverflow.com/badges), I find nothing that lets me know that a badge can be awarded multiple times.

I can see that I can click on badges individually to see if they can be awarded multiple times, but a simple icon or sentence in the badge list would make all the difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you click through to each individual badge, it will tell you.

[image: Archaeologist: only once]

vs.

[image: Favorite Question: multiple times]

A quicker way is to look through [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions).

---

[Mortarboard](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/144/mortarboard), in particular, is a one-time-only badge. But if you can reach 200 reputation on fifty separate occasions, you'll be [Epic](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/145/epic). For 150 days, you'll be [Legendary](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/146/legendary).

Comment: IMHO it **should** be placed in the badges page, so everything would be in the same place, a nice icon could be the answer... I'm not seeing anyone clicking in all badges just to see if they can be awarded multiple times :)

Comment: @balexandre: Then you might [feature-request] it.

Comment: good idea! done