# How many times can I earn vox-populi

Tags: support, badges, voting

I would like to know how many times in my entire life on Stack Exchange can I earn badges like vox-populi and suffrage, because I'm fully using my right to vote(that too responsibly!)(except once) and I know when those badges are awarded, my question is if I use my all votes on both questions and answers everyday, is there any possibility that I'll get those two badges everyday?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the Suffrage and Vox Populi badges are awarded once per site, for when you use a total of 30 and 40 votes for the first time in a UTC day respectively.

Please consult [this list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7425/273376) for badges that can be earned once or more than once.  The ones relevant for this question:

> Suffrage - Used 30 votes in a day (once)
>
> Vox Populi - Used the maximum 40 votes in a day (once)

Comment: Where is it mentioned?

Comment: @Integrator have edited with a link and further information