# Shouldn't we be scared to gain the Fanatic badge on SO?

Tags: discussion, badges

I didn't go through all badge definitions. But this one should be considered an alarm sign for people, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 6):

No, being on SO all the time is a sign of a normal, healthy developer. At least I hope so.

What should really be alarming is getting the Fanatic badge [on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/53/fanatic).

<sub>(See also: [How addicted to Stack Overflow are you?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11652/how-addicted-to-stack-overflow-are-you))</sub>

Comment: Hey! Meta is way cooler than SO

Comment: @Downvoter: Says the guy who doesn't have Fanatic here.

Comment: I was close, then I went to the beach for 2 weeks...

Answer (score 5):

Using Firefox? Good. Click on the site's icon next to the url, and click on `More Information...`
It counts how many times you've visited.
Now, that's alarming. The day count is peanuts...

Comment: *The day count is peanuts...* Yeah! You could have a completely *healthy* approach to SO and be here every day. Well, mostly healthy. .. Preeeeetty healthy.

Comment: Nice find! Now it only says 8450 times for me for SO, so I wonder how long ago I last cleared my browser cache... :)

Answer (score 1):

Using Safari? Good. Blame the badge on [Top Sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13727/did-safaris-top-sites-feature-earn-my-enthusiast-badge/15379#15379). ;-)

Comment: Or even if you've opened the sites in tabs on Firefox ;)