# Does deleted activity count towards enthusiast/fanatic?

Tags: discussion, badges, activity-badges, site-activity

As far as non-10k users are concerned, their comments and answers to questions that get deleted are gone, never to be seen again.  Rep lost on downvoting such questions is restored upon recalc.  Their own deleted questions evaporate from even their own profiles, along with any rep gained or lost for them.

Do actions involved in the above — posting an answer, submitting a vote, &c. — still count as activity for the purposes of calculating progress towards the enthusiast and fanatic badges, if the posts they're attached to are deleted?

Answer (score 6):

You just have to visit a page, no need to do any activity.

Comment: I thought this was corrected in a bugfix; will search.  Anecdotally, I used to always load all the sites at the same time (by middle-clicking a Firefox bookmark folder) and only got fanatic for SU.

Comment: @Pop: In order to be part of a bugfix, it would have to be a bug.  The badge description clearly states " **Visited** the site."

Comment: @Aarobot, there was once a related bug: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13727/did-safaris-top-sites-feature-earn-my-enthusiast-badge/15379#15379

Comment: Okay, found the source.  See Zombie Nixon's comment on this answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29303/enthusiast-fanatic-badge-do-we-need-to-just-visit-or-participate/29304#29304

Comment: You might need to force a reload. Just check that the "seen" field on your profile page is showing a time that indicates today.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an answer to the question, but [this answer by Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66482/consecutive-days-problem-97/66485#66485) clarifies/contradicts Kop's answer (depending on how you look at it).

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, Koper's answer is *almost* correct. For example, just visiting http://stackoverflow.com will *not* count as activity, but visiting https://stackoverflow.com/questions *will* count. I'm not 100% sure if this is true for all the sites, but this is how I got several badges.