# Why did my consecutive days disappear?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, consecutive-days

Yesterday I visited Stack Overflow and had 13 consecutive days visited.  Today, I visited and had 1.  Is this a bug?  Why did it reset?

Comment: Perhaps one of the many of us [with excess consecutive days](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54681/inconsistent-consecutive-days) have been syphoning them from you.

Comment: Maybe.  But I've seen that bug as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Two possibilities:

A bug about [inconsistent consecutive days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54681/inconsistent-consecutive-days) has been reported. This doesn't quite fit the profile of what you are seeing. Hard to say.

Another possibility: It is easy to visit Stack Overflow every day and still "miss a day." Stack Overflow's days starts at midnight (UTC, over in London somewhere <grin>). So a "Stack Overflow day" starts at (for example) 8pm Eastern Time. So it is conceivable that you can simply log in one morning and, if you don't check back until much later the next day... technically, you miss a day-as-tracked-by Stack Overflow.

Comment: So, because I live in Chicago, if I log in at 6pm Central Time, and log in the next day at 8pm, I've missed a day?  For a site about preventing incompetent programming, that seems highly dubious.

Comment: @Chris B: Come up with a better way to do it (that doesn't involve users having to set a timezone) and make a `feature-suggestion`.

Comment: @RobertCartaino considering this is a site about programming, I don't think people would mind setting their time zone if they knew about this.

Answer (score 11):

Just opening the home page does not count as a "visit".

There was a bug reported a while ago about Safari's "thumbnails" triggering a "visit" ([here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6834/got-woot-badge-unfairly-with-safari-4)) so you could actually achieve the Enthusiast and Fanatic badge without really visiting the site.

To get counted as a visit you have to visit another page and if you didn't do that it would reset your consecutive days counter.

See [Is there a minimum level of activity required to get the enthusiast badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21897/is-there-a-minimum-level-of-activity-required-to-get-the-enthusiast-badge)

Comment: Yeah, I opened the home page several times this morning, then I come back this evening to look at questions and notice the consecutive days reset, again.  I don't think a home page visit counts.

Answer (score 4):

While there were [a couple of bugs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54681/inconsistent-consecutive-days/55688#55688) in these site visit counters, your user history shows that you missed visiting on June 29th - please note that our servers operate on UTC time.

Comment: I'm not certain this one was part of that bug. It seems more like the user simply missed a day and the counter was reset.

Comment: @Jon you're most likely right - updating.

Comment: Is there a way for users to view their history to determine when they missed a day? I was a couple days away from earning my Fanatic badge on Stack Overflow and my profile is now saying I only have 3 consecutive days. I've been visiting Stack Overflow at noon and 8PM every day for months.

Comment: @Christopher this is something that we can look at doing.  For your issue, it looks like you missed August 7th :(  This has happened to me, as well!