# Are consecutive days counted as calendar days or 24 hour intervals?

Tags: discussion, consecutive-days

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Why did my consecutive days disappear?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55394/why-did-my-consecutive-days-disappear)
>   [Shouldn’t consecutive days measure from midnight to midnight in the user’s time zone?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55406/shouldnt-consecutive-days-measure-from-midnight-to-midnight-in-the-users-time-z)

I was on Stack Overflow around 5 p.m. on last Friday, then got back on around 9 p.m. Saturday. I was sad to see my consecutive days went back to 1. I was on for each day, but technically there was a 24 hour period that I was not on. So I was wondering if this is the correct way that it counts consecutive days (as 24 hours) or if it was a mistake?

Comment: Define "being on".

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55394/why-did-my-consecutive-days-disappear/55401#55401

Comment: I just realized I could check your profile for your timezone; you're listed as US Eastern, so yes, you missed an "SO day" (equivalent to a UTC day) in there.

Comment: Related: my own [equally-bad-but-in-a-different-way proposal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55483/proposed-consecutive-days-badge-tracking-change).