# Consecutive Days is Flawed

Tags: support, status-bydesign, consecutive-days

I just discovered that the consecutive day counter is not working correctly for me.  The number on my profile reset to 1 today, and I visited the site yesterday.  I came to the site this evening (7:30 PM) and I was on yesterday morning (10:00 AM).  How is this thing supposed to work?

Comment: yep, the time handling on SO is brain dead.

Comment: Four duplicates: [Are consecutive days counted as calendar days or 24 hour intervals?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58515/) , [Why did my consecutive days disappear?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55394) , [Shouldn't consecutive days measure from midnight to midnight in the user's time zone?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55406) , and [Change the definiton of a “day” to be localized for users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40119).

Comment: I still do not understand why it reset.  I guess the Fanatic badge will require me to schedule a task...

Comment: What @Jeff's edit means to me: it is flawed by design.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an SE "day"? When does each day start?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start)

Answer (score 17):

Days is based on UTC, not whatever local time you're currently at. If you are on Eastern Standard Time, for example, the day resets at 8PM (depending on daylight savings and other fun). Not sure about other timezones and such because I do not inhabit there.

Comment: If your sure its at 8PM EST, then here's the conversion for the rest of the world: http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?month=10&day=4&year=2010&hour=20&min=0&sec=0&p1=179&sort=2

Comment: When the "day resets" is highly irrelevant.  The problem here is that it is measuring hours and labeling it as days.

Comment: @user: How to you expect the server, which is located in one location on the globe, to magically divide the day according to whatever the local time of your computer is at that moment? Even if you made it some sort of per-user setting, then users would be able to game the system. So in general the system just uses Zulu time internally like every sane time system in the world.

Comment: You're missing the point.  UTC is fine.  24 hours is **not fine**!

Comment: @user: I don't understand how else it could be accomplished, without leaving holes which people could use to game the system.

Comment: @BillyONeal Check whether the user logged in 24-48 hours ago. If so, increment counter. Doesn't need to account for timezones.