# Consecutive days blatantly skipped one

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, consecutive-days

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Consecutive Days is Flawed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66526/consecutive-days-is-flawed)

Just logged in to check something on SO and I always see how many consecutive days I've got (trying to get a badge) .... turns out it skipped Sunday 22nd and marked me as visited for *tomorrow*?

Am I missing something, or is this server time and I managed to just miss it because of time difference? If so, lame.

[image: Skipped day?]

Answer (score 5):

Right now, SE time is at 1:08 AM. As such, it is now Monday. If you didn't visit in the 24 hours that occurred between 1 hour, eight minutes ago and 25 hours, eight minutes ago, then you did not visit on Sunday.

[image: Time]

I cannot check if you visited yesterday, but you were not *active* yesterday, which doesn't matter. I think a moderator would have to check, if they can even do that.

Comment: I tend to count my "days" as actual days when I'm visiting the site (i.e. I visited the site on Saturday, visited Sunday). Kind of a bummer to lose that streak on a technicality.

Comment: One always must be thinking that one lives in Greenwich.

Comment: When dealing with stuff on the web, you *have* to find out what the time context is before making assumptions.

Comment: I guess that comment is valid for a website dedicated to programmers who care about that sort of thing ... but for an average user, that's a pretty shoddy experience.

Comment: @MikeMurko How much does the average user really care about visiting the same website every day for 100 days just to get a yellow circle next to their name?

Comment: @murgatroid99 I'm going for it on EL&U :D I'm at 99 days.

Comment: @Mahnax I understand someone who is very involved in a site trying to get Fanatic (I have it on two sites), but I don't think the average user would care about it.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Depends, really.

Comment: A very simple solution is to check whether last viewed time is <24hrs from now, rather than me having to worry about what time it is in Greenwich.

Comment: @MikeMurko Nah, I think you should change all the clocks in your house.