# Consecutive visited days requires visiting w/in 24 hours of previous visit?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, visited-days

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is an SE “day”? When does each day start?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start)

I know there are several questions on this topic, but I couldn't find any that seemed to address my exact situation.

I was on SO yesterday (Friday, March 16 2012).  In my profile, right now, you can see I even asked a question.  Visiting the question, it shows 'asked yesterday'.

However, my profile also shows that my consecutive visited days is only 1.

What I'm guessing is that you actually have to visit w/in 24 hours of your last visit for it to be considered consecutive.  This is the only thing I can come up with that would explain how my consecutive visited days is only 1.

Is this how it's supposed to work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an SE "day"? When does each day start?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start), [Consecutive Days is Flawed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66526/consecutive-days-is-flawed), [Change the definition of a “day” to be localized for users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40119/change-the-definition-of-a-day-to-be-localized-for-users)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, Stack Exchange wraps the day around in UTC time, not in your local time and not in USA time.

Sounds like you had bad luck by visiting it right before the wrap and the next time right after the wrap... :(

Comment: +1 This is typically a point of confusion for me when reviewing previous posts. Other sites will show local time, I wonder why this is not done on SE.

Comment: @M.Babcock probably so we all see the same thing, easier to organize events..

Comment: @SimonSheehan - IMHO that makes it _more difficult_ to identify when an event happened. If necessary for mods then they should show the times in UTC to mods. I know what time it is here... if I see something different then I tend to be confused by it.

Comment: @M.Babcock or you just learn what time zone you're in and do basic math

Comment: @SimonSheehan - I didn't say I _couldn't figure out_ the time difference, but why should I have to? SE should be able to figure it out, or if it can't then it should ask in the preferences (a much too underutilized dialog). Even if it doesn't display my location based on it, it'd be better than having to do the translation myself if I decide to provide it. (Yes I do realize this is pushing laziness in favor of usability but in this case it would be worth it).

Comment: @M.Babcock: You can see the current UTC time by hovering over your user name in the top bar. It's in gray at the bottom of the menu that pops up.