# Consecutive days counter is wrong after midnight

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, consecutive-days, timezone, visited-days

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Consecutive Days is Flawed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66526/consecutive-days-is-flawed)

It's quarter past midnight and my consecutive/visited days counter is not including today. Is I'm in the UK, GMT timezone. Is this a UTC issue? GMT is currently UTC + 1.

Comment: There's still half an hour until the new day. SE follows UTC time. You can see the current server time by opening the drop-down box by hovering over your username at the top. It's at the bottom: *`UTC time 23:28`*

Comment: Being nitpicky: GMT and UTC are more or less synonyms. To quote Wikipedia, *[i]n the United Kingdom, GMT is the official time only during winter; during summer British Summer Time is used. GMT is the same as Western European Time.*

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail: This has been answered, literally, a *million* times before. I just don't feel like looking for a duplicate question with a terrible title.

Comment: Also to be nitpicky: GMT is not UTC + 1 at the moment. GMT is still the same as UTC. The UK is currently on BST, i.e. UTC + 1 (or CET but let's not get the Europhobes worried).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is calculated based on UTC time zone. Just like you, for me consecutive days counter changes at exact 5:30 am in the morning time.

You can also notice this time in your reputation history page, it always shows UTC time, when it was voteup/down or any other action taken.

Answer (score 1):

I know about the UTC time zone thing.  I still think it would be helpful to indicate on the user profile when the new day will start (either the local time of UTC midnight or hours until UTC midnight) - just above or below the number of consecutive days.