# Consecutive days reset

Tags: support, consecutive-days

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why did my consecutive days disappear?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55394/why-did-my-consecutive-days-disappear)

I was visiting the site every day for many days, and suddenly today the consecutive counter was reset, - so my question is - my it own fault or a bug from server side ?

Comment: See the _dozens_ of similar questions in the "Related" section to the right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably your own fault for not visiting every *UTC* day.

For example, if you're in a time zone with is UTC-8 (e.g. California) then you could visit at 3pm on Monday and then 5pm on Tuesday (both local time) - but the system sees that as 11pm Monday UTC and 1am Wednesday UTC, with no visit on Tuesday.

Comment: Whatever. it was just for a badge.

Comment: That's right, except for the calculation. 4pm PST (UST-8, includes Washington, Oregon, California of USA) is midnight UTC, so visiting at 7am on Monday PST is equivalent to 3pm on Monday, UTC, and 9am Tuesday, PST = 5pm Tuesday, UTC. If it were 3pm Monday, 5pm Tuesday, PST, then that's entirely correct.

Comment: Happened to me while trying to achieve Fanatic tag here on Meta.. luckily after I already got it on SO. Thanks for the clear explanation! :)

Comment: It's pretty much the most annoying badge requirement around. Guarantees somebody on a shift schedule, like myself, can't get it!

Comment: @Nightfirecat: Doh - that's what I get for trying to do this sort of thing before coffee. Will change it :)

Comment: @sixlettervariables Or being away (holiday) for a few days. Knowing with 00:00 UTC is you can of course cover a couple of days in a few minutes if that time is not too inconvenient.