# Is there a Problem in Local Time With StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why did my consecutive days disappear?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55394/why-did-my-consecutive-days-disappear)

My stackoverflow account was showing `visited   48 days, 24 consecutive` then I logged in at 2 Am in Midnight. and after That I logged after 36 hours. I expected it should show 26 Consecutive but Alas I saw it.. 50 days and 1 Consecative. I guess there is a problem with local time zone. Now I have to log in for one more month to earn `Enthusiast`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Anything based on "days" in the Stack Exchange system always means UTC days.

You can check the current UTC time by hovering over your name in the top toolbar.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Do you see anywhere on stackoverflow.com your local time? I don't. All times are UTC times. So I assume all their calculations are also based on UTC.