# Visited consecutive days

Tags: support, consecutive-days

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why did my consecutive days disappear?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55394/why-did-my-consecutive-days-disappear)

How is the consecutive days calculated when I lost my 84 days strike by not refreshing the page for about 18 hours..?

I live in UTC+2 and visited stackoverflow around 0830 this morning. It was showing 84 days on my consecutive days count. I didn't visit the time before now, 18 hours later at 0230, but it have now been reset to 1 day. Did I hit a bug? Are those 84 days lost, just like that?

Comment: Just like that.  The "consecutive days" calculation is intended to identify active users, not users trying to game the system, and I know you need to do more than just refresh the front page.  C'est la vie.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66482

Comment: I have the last 84 days made sure I was active on the page, so I am not trying to game the system. Refreshing the user info page does up the counter, so I would think that should be enough as well if you are having a busy day.. The 100 consecutive day badge also say "Visited the site each day for 100 consecutive days.". Doesn’t tell you that you need to "browse around"..

Comment: There are a number of features about SE that are kept secret to prevent gaming.  The intent and spirit of the badge is to award people who *participate,* not merely refresh a page.  Participation could be as simple as flagging a post for moderator attention, or voting to close an off-topic question.  Answering a question would almost certainly count as participation.  But merely refreshing a page doesn't contribute anything to the site, other than to chew up a little bandwidth.

Comment: I'm pretty sure even just voting for a good question or answer counts as activity towards the consecutive days visited badges.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. But out of those 84 days, I am sure one of them was only hitting my morning routine with checking in on the page for new interesting questions, in other words, one page refresh..

Comment: I see nothing in the logs for you at what would've been June 15 06:30 UTC - I suppose it's possible you got a cached page or accessed the site from a different IP without being logged in, but from this end at least there's no evidence that you were here. Sorry.

Answer (score 12):

You missed it by just over 26 minutes. You accessed the site on June 14th at 20:43:57 UTC, and then didn't touch it again until June 16th at 0:26:50 UTC.

Better luck next time...