# Consecutive days don't seem to maintain count properly

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why did my consecutive days disappear?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55394/why-did-my-consecutive-days-disappear)

I've noticed this issue many of times over as I am currently pursuing or have been trying rather to get the badges for x days consecutively logged in, and visiting stack. Specifically on Stack Overflow. However, like I said for a long time now I have noticed a random glitch. Ill be active for 30-40 days at a max before it resets to zero. But thats its not specific to that range sometimes it will reset in less days.

All in all I make it part of my routine to at least visit the site daily, and either do a few reviews, or peruse through some Questions looking to comment or make an answer, or whatever the case, I've actively used the site in one shape way form or another and ensured that I was actually logged in while doing so. With that it seems the days I do not make an actual post or comment by the next day my count is off to 0 again. Or sometimes Ill only login once during the day on days I am out running around (usually the weekends) but none the less. Ill login and view around to see if theres anything I can assist on, then by later that day back to zero.

Can anyone shed some light and enlighten me as to possible reasons for this? As I would like to one day eventually earn those badges, starting to feel like an uphill battle though as every time I get months in I lose it to something random like above mentioned

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/55401/149052

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ I think that hit the nail right on the head. That would explain it on the days it seems like an overlap despite me being active, day in day out, the time difference for me, if stacks day starts 8pm eastern, that means 11pm pacific for me. I can see how that overlap might effect me on some days with my schedule and habits, thank you.

Comment: You can take advantage of this cutoff; if you visit the site at 7:59 PM Eastern and 8:01 PM Eastern it will count as two days. This helps you stay on track when you think you might miss a day on the weekend or something.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that the rollover is somewhere between 8pm and 6pm where i live.  I think It might be at 12.00 a.m. GMT.

If i post at like 9 p.m. it will be as though i was posting during the next day

if you click on the `XXX days, XX consecutive` it will bring up a calendar with which days you were active marked on it.

Comment: Yes, the new day starts at 00:00 UTC.