# Bug: Counting Consecutive Reset

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I'm facing a problem with my loggin consecutive count. Today, it was reset back to 1. I've never missed a day since March 21. Please check and let me know. Thanks so much. 
[image: calendar]

**UPDATE:**
This is my Calender in SO.
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you visited the site logged in with your account on the 8th and 9th?

Comment: Yes I'm. Everyday, I logged in with SO and META. I usually switch between them.

Comment: The days tracked are UTC days. What time zone are you in? If you log in at 9AM Tuesday and then noon on Wednesday, that's once a day for two days, but there's more than 24 hours (an entire day) between. If a UTC day happens to fall in there, you've missed it.

Comment: Where are you located? Keep in mind that SO/SE uses UTC time. Might differing time zones have caused you to miss days?

Comment: @RaghavSood I have added a calendar in SO, please check. Thanks.

Comment: Additionally, simply loading the home page doesn't count as a visit; you need to actually visit a few pages. Are you sure you did that every day?

Comment: My timezone is: (UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)

Comment: Thanks everyone, the reason may be missing action in META on the 8th and 9th. But I didn't know about that until today. It should be included in a guide for SO and META. +1 for everyone. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the reason from a reply on [similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/55401/212576)

> It is easy to visit Stack Overflow every day and still "miss a day."
>   Stack Overflow's days starts at midnight (UTC, over in London
>   somewhere ). So a "Stack Overflow day" starts at (for example)
>   8pm Eastern Time.

Another reason(again [answered here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66485/212576)) can be:

> No access to internal pages (login pages, along with a number of other
>   homepage style pages, don't count as "access").

Comment: It's reasonable. But I didn't know about that until today. May be it should be included in guide for both SO and META. Thanks @hjpotter92

Answer (score 3):

On meta for those days you only visited the home page, and took no other action.  The home page explicitly [does not count as activity for a day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66482/consecutive-days-problem-97).

Visit a question, voting, commenting...anything but visiting the home page counts as activity for a day.

Comment: @KhanhTran - not a problem, sorry for the confusion!

Comment: no problem, we learn a lesson everyday. So, we improve. Thanks.