# Is there any way to check if is specific user currently logged in?

Tags: support, users

Is there any way to check if a specific user is currently logged in? I know that in the user profile there is a value for "seen", but it isn't always relevant (e.g., user logged out 2 minutes ago, but you see - oh, he has been active 2 minutes ago, so I can think he is still active, I will write to him). If it isn't I will write a feature request.

Comment: I'm always logged in, since I never [log out](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/logout).

Comment: the seen .... ago is cashed so sometimes it will not reflect the to-the-minute truth

Comment: @Wooble SE uses also Javascript

Comment: User can log in, visit a question page and leave the browser open for whole year without ever actually being near the computer. Does it mean he's "logged in"? Technically he is, but he's not active.

Comment: You can't see that besides the  `seen` indicator in the profile which has a 30 minute update window. And I would not want to be stalked like that.

Comment: On my mobile I almost always have stack exchange windows open that I haven't actually looked at for weeks

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd "Check if specific user is currently active" would be a better question then :).

Comment: i dont want to be monitored and i dont want to have my every move recorded and stored somewhere...just be more patient people who are here on daily basis will come back and see your comment if you use the @

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't, and this wouldn't work well if it were to be implemented.

If a user was reading through a lengthy answer, for instance, they'd be *active* on the site, but there wouldn't be any way that StackOverflow could know that unless it monitored every mouse movement, page scroll, key press or eye movement a user made.

Comment: I believe such technology is available, whats the name for it..... I I can't remember. I believe its important to install it without the user noticing because that would lead them to inconvenience themselves by uninstalling it

Comment: You forgot one important thing: Stack Overflow also must monitor the user's thoughts, he might be just thinking about question or answer he saw, hence active.

Answer (score 6):

No, there is not.

The 'seen' field and the 'activity' tab on the profile is the only evidence you have of someone visiting the site.

Comment: Stalking works as well .... nice pants.

Comment: Really? You like them? I thought they made me look.. lazy. In bed with a cold today, I thought I could get away with them.

Comment: I guess *evidence* is [too strong of a statement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6834/got-woot-badge-unfairly-with-safari-4).